# How to connect multiple Raspberry Pi's (v3) to Django for a SPA

Tags: django, single-page-application, raspberry-pi3

So I'm trying to make a SPA to read different raspberry pi's sensor values on real time, and to change them as well. I've got some knowledge on Django, SQL, React and JS.

As I lack experience using Rpi's, I've done some research and found that I need to set up Django in the Rpi's. However, this causes me the following concern:

- Should I set up a different Django Project for every Rpi that I have? (lets say I got 10 RPi3, so it would be 10 Django Projects).

If true, shouldn't be weird having multiple projects when is actually one? And how can I coordinate all of them so that I can display them in the same page (React component)?

On the other case, should I have only one Django Project that gathers the information of all Rpi's? How can I make this possible?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need many Django Applications, one is enough. If you want to go raspberry only you could even dedicate one clearly to Django and have the rest and data publishers.

Your question can be bascially divied into two parts:

1. Sending data from Raspberries to Django
2. Receiving data on Raspberries (from Django)

The first one is quite easy, you could just write a python or bash script that sends data periodically over http/https to the Django API.

The second one, however, requires some form of inbound gateway for your raspberries. Which one is only on your choice.. TCP, HTTP, HTTPS.. As you would be able to manipulate GPIOs you'd want some form of authentication.

If you dont care about security at all, you can just spin up a very simple flask api on each raspberry node, for example with one endpoint with two arguments, gpio number, and value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :), however I didn't get what you mean with "to dedicate one clearly to Django"? Like having a Django Project developed in my PC, and let all my RPi's consume my API?

Comment: You can either run Django on your PC, or on one of the raspberries, if you want to go raspberry only. Then let all the other raspberries interacting with this one django API